# Function to search if one network is contained in another network

Tags: go

I need an efficient way in Go to take one CIDR network and test if it is wholly contained in other networks.

Example:

```
var (
    subnet string = "10.10.10.8/29"
    route string = "10.10.10.0/24"
)
```

I want to test if 'subnet' is in 'route' and return true because it is.  Return false for values that are not within 'route' or partially outside it.

I have a solution for testing if a single host is in a network using IP/CIDR parsing and 'x.Contains()' in package net.  I have tried adapting this for networks and it failed.

**This does not work:**.

```
if route.Contains(subnet) {
    fmt.Println("%s subnet is contained subnet %s",net, route)
}
```

*Edit:  There is apparently some confusion over this. The snipet of code just above this paragraph here that does not work for me to test if one network is inside another. The SO overflow guidelines asked me to be specific about what I have tried so that is why I put this in here. This is my first SO post.*

I have some ideas that are bulkier than I would like to do this with this one in the lead:

Calculate the first IP (network IP) and last ip (broadcast IP) of 'subnet', using 'net.ParseCIDR()' and known subnet sizes as constants, and then test if both the network and broadcast IP of 'subnet' are in 'route' with 'x.Contains()'.

Edit:  I did not see this thread in my initial searches but came across it now.  It is similar so I am linking here for completeness.  [ [How to detect if two Golang net.IPNet objects intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729158/how-to-detect-if-two-golang-net-ipnet-objects-intersect) ]

Comment: What does not work? Your function doesn't do anything, except print some output to stdout.

Comment: In any case, you should probably use the [IPNet.Contains](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPNet.Contains) method.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/KP9mI4xRLZg IPv6 left as an exercise.

Comment: @Peter. Thank you so much--that works but I will need too spend some time picking it apart figure out how it works.  I am new to Go, and I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction and you wrote it out--thanks!.  Once I go through it I will mark your comment as the answer--in the next day.

Comment: Think about the definition of a subnet: The set of addresses with a particular common prefix. So to figure out if A contains B you have to check if A is a prefix of B.

Comment: @Peter I have worked through it and it is an interesting approach and what I was hoping for.  Only, I have found some situations where it does not work as I hoped.  It seem to provide consistent positive matches but can provide false matches.  I took your code and broke it out with print statements here:  [ https://play.golang.org/p/WqPdErR12UO ]. Note that I compare here two small /29 networks that are close though completely separate, but the code still returns true.  This has given me a lot to think about and I will try to figure some way to tweak this to get the needed result.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For any `x` and `y` IPv4s, and any integers `m` and `n` from 0-32, the network `x/m` is contained in `y/n` if and only if `m >= n` and `x` is in `y/n` (you can work out the proof for this yourself).  Therefore, the following will work:

```
func contains(subnet, route string) (bool, error) {
    sIP, sNW, err := net.ParseCIDR(subnet)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    _, rNW, err := net.ParseCIDR(route)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    sNWMaskSize, _ := sNW.Mask.Size()
    rNWMaskSize, _ := rNW.Mask.Size()

    return rNW.Contains(sIP) && sNWMaskSize >= rNWMaskSize, nil
}
```

Comment: I have not forgotten your answer just been busy.  I will go through it carefully soon.

Answer (score 1):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can check containment using the same code for networks or addresses, for CIDR subnets or other subnets, for IPv4 or IPv6. Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    contains("10.10.10.0/24", "10.10.10.8/29")
    contains("172.17.0.0/16", "172.17.192.0/18")
    contains("172.17.0.0/16", "172.17.191.0/18")
    contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.3/32")
    contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.3")
    contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.5")
    contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.0/31")
    contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.1-3")
    contains("1::/64", "2::/72")
    contains("1::/64", "1::/32")
    contains("1::/64", "1::/112")
    contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::4:5-6")
    contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::3-4:5")
    contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::4:5-7")
    contains("1-2::/64", "2::/64")
    contains("bla", "foo")
}

func contains(route, subnet string) {
    containingAddr, containedAddr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(route),
        ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(subnet)
    fmt.Printf("%s contains %s %v\n", containingAddr, containedAddr,
        containingAddr.Contains(containedAddr))
}
```

Output:

```
10.10.10.0/24 contains 10.10.10.8/29 true
172.17.0.0/16 contains 172.17.192.0/18 true
172.17.0.0/16 contains 172.17.191.0/18 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.3/32 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.3 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.5 false
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.0/31 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.1-3 true
1::/64 contains 2::/72 false
1::/64 contains 1::/32 false
1::/64 contains 1::/112 true
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::4:5-6 true
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::3-4:5 true
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::4:5-7 false
1-2::/64 contains 2::/64 true
bla contains foo false
```